# Increase Placeholder Length

Tags: webforms, input-formats

I have a `webform` that has a `textarea` `input`. I am trying to update the `placeholder` text. It seems to have a limit of `128 chars`. Is it possible to update this to allow for a longer placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

I created a ticket for this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2878255) in the Webform module's issue queue and fixed the problem.

The best solution was to convert the placeholder input from a text field to a textarea so that you can now enter multiple lines of text as the textarea's placeholder.